# Do I need to provide an equality function when I provide a hash function to std::unorder_set class

Tags: c++11

I need to provide my own hash function for std::unordered_set template class, it seems by looking over internet that I need to provide equality function too ? does it true ? and if yes I'm wondering why the hash key can't be used to do the equality test?

Comment: `std::unordered_set` is not a class

Answer (score 0):

Hash functions can have collisions (two keys hash to the same value).